# Creating a date of birth field in registration system to see if user is old enough using momentjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs

I'm trying to validate whether my user is older than 13 as part of a user registration system using nodejs and momentjs. I have var years to represent how old the user is and I want some way to be able to check whether that value is greater than 13 while still following the format of my form validator. I'm not sure if there is an easier way to do this.

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name; 
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password; 
  var password2 = req.body.password2; 
  var bday = req.body.bday; 
  var birthday = moment(bday); 
  var years = moment().diff(birthday, 'years'); 

  // Form Validator
  req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email','Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password','Password field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);
  req.checkBody('bday', 'Date of Birth field is required').notEmpty(); 
  req.checkBody('bday', 'Date of Birth must be in valid format').isValid(); 
  req.checkBody('bday', 'User must be older than 13').

  // Check Errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();
```

Comment: Moment is a very decent library and unless you are learning Javascript or just want to write your own implementation using diff() is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try using moment's `diff` function to check if the number of years is greater than 13.

```js
let arr = ["2017-01-29T17:24:22+0000", "2004-01-29T17:24:22+0000"];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(moment().diff(arr[i], "years") > 13);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```